# How to upload input file for batch prediction in gcloud ml-engine?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to create a batch prediction job in google cloud ml-engine. Unfortunately, I always get the same error:

```
{
    insertId:  "wr85wwg6shs9ek"   
    logName:  "projects/tensorflow-test-1-168615/logs/ml.googleapis.com%2Ftest_job_23847239"   
    receiveTimestamp:  "2017-08-04T16:07:29.524193256Z"   
    resource: {
        labels: {
            job_id:  "test_job_23847239"     
            project_id:  "tensorflow-test-1-168615"     
            task_name:  "service"     
        }
        type:  "ml_job"    
    }
    severity:  "ERROR"   
    textPayload:  "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported"   
    timestamp:  "2017-08-04T16:07:29.524193256Z"   
}
```

I create the file in java and upload it to a bucket with the following code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(media.getUrl()));
int[][][] imageMatrix = convertToImageToMatrix(bufferedImage);
String imageString = matrixToString(imageMatrix);
String inputContent = "{\"instances\": [{\"inputs\": " + imageString + "}]}";
byte[] inputBytes = inputContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Blob inputBlob = mlInputBucket.create(media.getId().toString() + ".json", inputBytes, "application/json");
inputPaths.add("gs://" + Properties.getCloudBucketNameInputs() + "/" + inputBlob.getName());
```

In this code, I download the image, convert it to uint8 matrix and format the matrix as a json string. The file gets created and is present in the bucket. I also verified, that the json file is valid.

In the next step, I collect all created files and start the prediction job:

```
GoogleCloudMlV1PredictionInput input = new GoogleCloudMlV1PredictionInput();
input.setDataFormat("TEXT");
input.setVersionName("projects/" + DatastoreOptions.getDefaultProjectId() + "/models/" + Properties.getMlEngineModelName() + "/versions/" + Properties.getMlEngineModelVersion());
input.setRegion(Properties.getMlEngineRegion());
input.setOutputPath("gs://" + Properties.getCloudBucketNameOutputs() + "/" + jobId);
input.setInputPaths(inputPaths);

GoogleCloudMlV1Job job = new GoogleCloudMlV1Job();
job.setJobId(jobId);
job.setPredictionInput(input);
engine.projects().jobs().create("projects/" + DatastoreOptions.getDefaultProjectId() , job).execute();
```

Finally, the job gets created but the result is the one from the beginning.

I also tried to start the job with the gcloud sdk, but the result is the same. But when I modify the file to remove the `instances` object and match the correct format for for [online prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/prediction-overview#online_prediction_input_data), it works (To make it work, I need to remove the most of the rows from the input, because of the payload quota for online predictions).

I'm using the trained pets model from the [object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection). One of my created input files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LzDebt2EYGUU5xS2dWcGM3aHM/view?usp=sharing).

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did I answer your question in [tensorflow serving prediction not working with object detection pets example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375031/tensorflow-serving-prediction-not-working-with-object-detection-pets-example/45381837#45381837)? The input of batch prediction should not include '{"instances: }'.

Comment: ok, now I'm confused. I thought, 'instances' should be written, when we want to do a batch prediction job. Hmm, I think I have overlooked this.