# gcloud local prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml-engine

I trained a Pet dataset onto Google cloud, downloaded the trained model to local PC, using gcloud.
Task: To classify test set, locally with the trained model

A) If I use gcloud like

```
    $ gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=saved_model/ --json-instances=inputs.json
```

Error: prediction_lib.PredictionError: (4, "Exception during running the graph: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0'")

Comment: Can you provide the contents of inputs.json (feel free to "Edit out" binary blobs).

Comment: It looks like your model accepts a numpy array of a graph but the input contains some string (jpeg string?). Can you run: $ saved_model_cli show --dir ${YOUR_LOCAL_MODEL_DIR --all and paste the results here as well as a snippet of inputs.json as rhaertel80 said?

Comment: JSON : {"b64": "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
.........................

Comment: ```signature_def['serving_default']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_UINT8
    shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
    name: image_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 300, 4)
    name: detection_boxes:0
outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 300)
    name: detection_classes:0```

Answer (score 2):

Your model does accept an array for the image, not JPG strings. Please see the answer to
[tensorflow serving prediction not working with object detection pets example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375031/tensorflow-serving-prediction-not-working-with-object-detection-pets-example/45381837#45381837)

If you want to use your current input, you may re-export the model with --input_type encoded_image_string_tensor.