# Batch prediction for object detection fails on Google Cloud platform

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I exported a faster_rcnn_resnet101 model with custom classes for serving predictions and deployed it on Cloud ML platform so that I can use Cloud ML prediction engine. Online prediction works but the results fail when I try batch prediction. It appears that the official documentation is outdated and needs an update.

I tried formatting my data in both ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375031/tensorflow-serving-prediction-not-working-with-object-detection-pets-example/45381837#45381837). In addition I also tried the request format mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request).

I also tried the steps mentioned in the [google cloud blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/performing-prediction-with-tensorflow-object-detection-models-on-google-cloud-machine-learning-engine).

Local prediction and online prediction work but the batch prediction fails. Any help will be much appreciated.

Error Log:

('Exception during running the graph: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]\n\t [[node map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:210)  = Assert[T=[DT_STRING], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/is_bmp, map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert/data_0)]]', 1)

Answer (score 0):

Our apologies, but batch prediction is not currently supported for custom models.

Comment: By custom model, I mean only the object classes. The model, however, was trained with resnet101 as backbone. Does this answer still apply?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. This is a feature we would like to add.